# Using Json.Net ContractResolver and inner reference properties

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

While writing our API, we came across the requirement to filter out properties of a model that the requesting user does not have access to.

Using Json.Net ContractResolver we were able to address this requirement for the most part.

```
public class ConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        //filter the properties and return back the final list
    }
}
```

However in scenarios that the reference properties are eager-loaded, the ContactResolver seems to be ineffective. 
For example for the following class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}
public class Account 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Website { get; set; }
   public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

When the Contact is being queried, the Account record could be eager loaded, when serializing to JSON, the ContractResolver will be only applying the filter on the Contact fields, not the Account fields.

```
Contact data = new Contact { 
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Duo",
    AccountId = 123,
    Account = new Account { Id=123, Name="My Company", Website="www.mycompany.com" }
};
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, 
     Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
     new JsonSerializerSettings { 
       ContractResolver= new ConverterContractResolver() 
     });
```

Is there any way to have Json.net call the same Contract Resolver for the reference properties as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I found out that the ContractResolver is called for **each referenced object within my model as well**.
Which is nice in part, however somewhat problematic, since it only passes the type of the object being parsed to JSON and no information about the depth or where it has found the object.

```
public class ConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
     protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, 
                   Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
     {
         //filter the properties and return back the final list
     }
}
```

By adding a counter to the number of times the CreateProperties is being called, I managed to recognize which call is for the main model and which subsequent calls are for referenced objects.

This partially resolved my problems and now the same ContractorResolver applies the filtering to all referenced objects in my models.

Comment: what happen if contact have two account properties of same type "Account" and you need to filter out properties differently for this two object of type "Account" ?